# MKMapView - iphone development

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

i have a navigation-based app.
the first view is a tableView, when i press the third cell i'll get navigated into a MapViewController

```
else if (2 == indexPath.row)
    {   MapViewController *maps = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];
        maps.title=@"Maps";
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:maps animated:YES];
        [maps release];
    }
```

what's wrong with this code? i'm getting an error !

Comment: the view is not loading (not navigating)

Comment: 2011-07-24 01:41:03.663 CafeYounes[11858:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (MKMapView)'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `MapKit.framework` to your Xcode project.

Xcode 4

1. Select your Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.
2. Click the little "+" in lower right corner.
3. Add `MapKit.framework`
4. Recompile